# What are core threads in a ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I was looking at the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class and I found that it allows to specify the maximum pool size and the core pool size.

I understand, a little, about when to change the core and maximum pool sizes based on the answer here: [When is specifying separate core and maximum pool sizes in ThreadPoolExecutor a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492922/when-is-specifying-separate-core-and-maximum-pool-sizes-in-threadpoolexecutor-a)

However, I would like to know what are these 'core threads'. I always get 0 when I use the `getCorePoolSize()` method of a `ThreadPoolExecutor`

SSCCE here:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class PoolSize {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a cached thread pool
        ExecutorService cachedPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        // Cast the object to its class type
        ThreadPoolExecutor pool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) cachedPool;

        // Create a Callable object of anonymous class
        Callable<String> aCallable = new Callable<String>(){
            String result = "Callable done !";
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                // Print a value
                System.out.println("Callable at work !");
                // Sleep for 5 sec
                Thread.sleep(0);
                return result;
            }
        };

        // Create a Runnable object of anonymous class
        Runnable aRunnable = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Print a value
                    System.out.println("Runnable at work !");
                    // Sleep for 5 sec
                    Thread.sleep(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        // Submit the two tasks for execution
        Future<String> callableFuture = cachedPool.submit(aCallable);
        Future<?> runnableFuture = cachedPool.submit(aRunnable);

        System.out.println("Core threads: " + pool.getCorePoolSize());
        System.out.println("Largest number of simultaneous executions: " 
                                            + pool.getLargestPoolSize());
        System.out.println("Maximum number of  allowed threads: " 
                                            + pool.getMaximumPoolSize());
        System.out.println("Current threads in the pool: " 
                                            + pool.getPoolSize());
        System.out.println("Currently executing threads: " 
                                            + pool.getTaskCount());

        pool.shutdown(); // shut down

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

core threads is the minimum which is always running just in case you want to pass it a task.  The cached pool by default has a core of `0` as you might expect.

For the fixed thread pool, the core and the maximum are the same i.e. whatever you set the fixed size to.

Comment: OK so if in a `cached thread pool` I change the number of core threads then akin to a `fixed thread pool`, these guys will always be there. However, the threads not used for longer than a minute will be discarded. Net result is combining the benefits of both cached and fixed thread pool. Right ?

Comment: You end up creating a pool which has few threads which are always in stand-by and other threads are created as needed. Idle threads will not consume memory as the resources they take will be released.

Answer (score 0):

The `core threads` are just standard threads but will be always kept alive in the pool, and then the other non-core threads will end their lives after the run() method finished.

But how could these `core threads` be always alive? That's because they are always waiting for taking a task from the `workQueue` shared within the pool. By default, the `workQueue` is a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), its `take()` method will block the current thread indefinitely until a task becomes available.

Here comes the key point, which threads will become the `core threads`? They may not be the first started ones or the last ones, but the ones(corePoolSize) that last the longest. Easier to understand from the code.

```html
private Runnable getTask() {
        boolean timedOut = false; // Did the last poll() time out?

        for (;;) {
            int c = ctl.get();
            int rs = runStateOf(c);

            // Check if queue empty only if necessary.
            if (rs >= SHUTDOWN && (rs >= STOP || workQueue.isEmpty())) {
                decrementWorkerCount();
                return null;
            }

            int wc = workerCountOf(c);

            //------------- key code ------------------
            // Are workers subject to culling?
            boolean timed = allowCoreThreadTimeOut || wc > corePoolSize;

            if ((wc > maximumPoolSize || (timed && timedOut))
                && (wc > 1 || workQueue.isEmpty())) {
                if (compareAndDecrementWorkerCount(c))
                    return null;
                continue;
            }

            //------------- key code ------------------
            try {
                Runnable r = timed ?
                    workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) :
                    workQueue.take();
                if (r != null)
                    return r;
                timedOut = true;
            } catch (InterruptedException retry) {
                timedOut = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

What I just said above is based on `allowCoreThreadTimeOut` set as `false`.

Actually, I prefer to call `core threads` as `core workers`.